# Where does the mac shell (terminal) look for the instructions for commands such as ls, cd, etc

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal

I believe the title says it all, I know that some of these commands can be found in places like /usr/bin but I'd like to know the details of all the folders than can be found in, or what the process of locating them is.

Comment: Open up *Terminal* and type in the command `echo $PATH`.  That should give you the array of directories in which commands and utilities are located and searched for by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know where a specific command is being found, enter:

```
which command
```

For example:

```
which ls
```

And as CJK mentioned, echo $PATH shows you all the directories that are being searched (in the order they are searched) for commands.

A few commands, such as cd, are built into the shell, and don't need to be found anywhere, although there might be a program implementation as well. The command "type", as in:

```
type -a cd
```

...will specifically tell you that a command is built in.

More info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116955/where-is-cd-located

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a *mac shell*, and the correct answer depends on the shell which you are actually using. But if you just used the default settings, your shell will be *bash*, and in this case, the `type` command will do the trick, for example:

```
type ls
```

However, if you really have bash, you need to be careful with aliases: If you have an alias *foo* and an executable *foo*,

```
type foo
```

will report the alias, but inside a non-interactive context (shell script), aliases are not expanded, and the executable *foo* is used.

If you follow the advice given in the answer from @kshetline, i.e. to use

```
type -a foo
```

you find all places where *foo* would be found, in search order. For instance, in my bash

```
type -a ls
```

outputs

```
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /usr/bin/ls
```